# How to build a functionality to download Audio files to local folder or downloads folder from a silverlight application?

Tags: vb.net, audio, silverlight-5.0, audio-streaming

I have a silverlight web application, in which I have a functionality to play an audio/sound files.Currently sound files are stored in Client Bin folder, sound files can be in any folder on server.I want to build a functionality to 
download these sound files to users pc.
I tried using save file dialog,but couldn't download the audio files.

Comment: @JLILI Aman  I tried with web client but I need some example code.I am not able to download audio files... What is the exact process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is-
I got the audio files from client bin folder from server then I downloaded it to local folder on client machine by using save file dialog box.
as follows-

```
 Private Sub btn_downloadSound_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    If streamAudio_download Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Audio file does not exists for selected sound feature")
    Else
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "MP3 Files (*.mp3)|*.mp3|MP4 Files|*.mp4"
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim words As String() = soundFileSelected_Name.Split(".")
        Dim fileExtension As String = words(1)
        Using audiofs As System.IO.FileStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If fileExtension = "mp3" Then
                Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(40) {}
                Dim bytesToRead As Integer = 0
                bytesToRead = streamAudio_download.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

                While (bytesToRead = streamAudio_download.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) <> 0
                    audiofs.Write(bytes, 0, bytesToRead)
                End While
            ElseIf fileExtension = "mp4" Then
                Dim b As New BinaryWriter(audiofs)
                b.Write(byteArray)
                audiofs.Close()
            End If
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
[webclient methods not available to my Silverlight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308578/webclient-methods-not-available-to-my-silverlight-application)

> You can best achieve what you want in Silverlight by using
>   WebClient.OpenReadCompleted and OpenReadAsync. This will return a
>   stream. You can use that directly, or copy the stream into a byte[] as
>   described here for example:
>   http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

Comment: I am  using silverlight+vb.net  if I use this code,I get error message that DownloadFile is not member of weclient. I have included system.net